# how to run mysql_tzinfo_to_sql via golang

Tags: mysql, go

I want to import time zone information into MySQL using Golang.
Now i use "exec.Command"

but "pa -aux" will display the password
How to avoid it? thx

```
    script := fmt.Sprintf(`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u %s --password=%s mysql`, username, password)
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", script)
```